# Pi Zero W - Switching camera LED from program or command line

Tags: camera, led, pi-zero-w

So far failing to switch the camera LED either from Python using RPi.GPIO or from the command line using /sysfs/gpio...  I've tried using both GPIO5 and GPIO32 as suggested from various online sources, but haven't found any source specifically refer to the Pi zero or zero w and camera led GPIO.

The camera LED is disabled by config.txt - but setting up GPIO as output and state 'True' or 'False' via Python, or directly as '0' or '1' using /sysfs/gpio does nothing (all done using root shell).  Is it possible to switch the CSI camera led on the Pi zero without rebooting?

Comment: Had a look a the value of /sys/class/gpio/gpio5/value after setting (using 'cat /sys/class/gpio5/value' )and it remains unchanged.  Is this a problem with the O/S (motioneyeos)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much searching I attempted to use an overlay as detailed here https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1332 however on checking the source dts file it appears that the camera led for the pi zero w is set as gpio40.  The answer is that simple - using /sys/class/gpio I am able to switch the led (or in my case using a waveshare camera with IR-Cut IR-filter) on and off simply using gpio40.  (I'm using motioneyeos so admin user is root).  With

```
disable_camera_led=1
```

in config.txt: the following commands run as root user will switch the led on (or IR cut filter in depending on your camera).

```
$>echo 40 > /sys/class/gpio/export
$>echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio40/direction
$>echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio40/value
```

To switch back out again;

```
$>echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio40/value
```

I haven't test from Python, but I expect that it will work fine using RPI.BCM and gpio40.